# Are mailto: links a problem?

Tags: hyperlinks, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using mailto: links for email addresses…what is the practice these days?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2648/using-mailto-links-for-email-addresses-what-is-the-practice-these-days)

What percent of the US sees a dead Outlook popup when they click a mailto: link?

Most amateur web designers know that forms are probably the best way to let a user send an email, but what about when that's not an option?

How many users will hate me when they try to contact me through:

```
<a href="mailto:sample@sample.com">this</a>
```